# Let $f$ be Lebesgueable integrable, then $\lim_{h\to 0}\sup \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)| = 0$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, limsup-and-liminf, absolute-continuity

I must show that

Let $f$ be Lebesgueable integrable, then

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\sup \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy = 0$$

for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tentative proof:

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \geq 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{h\to 0}\sup \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy \geq 0$$

We must show that

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\sup \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy \leq 0$$

I will show that for any $\epsilon >0$

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\sup \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy < \epsilon$$

If $f(x) = 0$, By absolute continuity of integration, for any $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$ such that if

$$ m({|x-y| < h}) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(y)|dy <\frac{\epsilon}{2} $$

Now $$ \lim_{h\to 0}\sup m({|x-y| < h}) \leq m({|x-y| < h}) < \delta$$

then

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\sup \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy < \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon $$

Now for $f(x) \neq 0$,

$$\int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy \leq \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x)|dy + \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(y)|dy $$

$$= |f(x)|m({|x -y| < h}) + \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(y)|dy $$

and $|f(x)| < \infty$ for allmost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Let $\delta^{*} < \min \{\delta,\frac{\epsilon}{2|f(x)|}\}$, now by absolute continuiuty of integration, for $\epsilon > 0$,
$$m({|x -y| < h}) < \delta^{*} < \delta \Rightarrow \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy \leq |f(x)|m({|x -y| < h}) + \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(y)|dy < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

For almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence,

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\sup m({|x-y| < h}) \leq m({|x-y| < h}) < \delta^{*} < \delta \Rightarrow  \lim_{h\to 0}\sup\int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy < \epsilon $$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\sup \int_{|x -y| < h}|f(x) - f(y)|dy = 0$$

for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry but is a bit complicate to read your proof (too long ^^).  btw, it's not clear if you integrate wrt $x$, $y$ or both. Anyway, for me it's just monotone convergence with $g_n(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|\boldsymbol 1_{\{|x-y|<\frac{1}{n}\}}$. Should work, no ?

Comment: its with respect to $y$. And I see what you mean, but that set is not increasing $|x-y| < 1/n$ is decreasing.

Comment: @Surb i fix the differentials, anyway it was obvious from the proof that it's $dy$ because I consider $f(x)$ as constant under the integral. And monotone convergence theorem is for increasing sequences and that sequence is decreasing.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about Dominated theorem convergence. Anyway, it's almost straightforward ;-)

Comment: @Surb I think it should work as well. I already prove it with your assumption.  It will look weird tho. Lol. I proved that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n(x) = 0$ then the $\lim\sup = 0$ as well.